# Understanding「たとえ思うだけでも思わないでください」

Tags: grammar

A lady faces a monster and she have an ability to harm that monster just by thinking cruel things in her head, like mentally visualizing stabbing that monster with knife for example. The monster wails in pain and told her

> お願いだから、後生だから、そんな酷いことを思わないでくださいな、**たとえ思うだけでも思わないでください**

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the bold part well. I think it means "At least, please don't think just by thinking"?

What does たとえ mean? How だけでも works here?

Comment: (very often) たとえ goes hand in hand with て(で)も https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2020/05/29/jlptn3-grammar-tatoe-temo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the comment, たとえ・・・でも is usually translated as *even if ...*. So the part literally means *don't think (cruel things) even if (you) just think (cruel things).*

A neutral reading is that *to think (of cruel things)* is contrasted with *to do (cruel things)*. The monster says *Your  thinking is already harmful, even if you don't actually do those things, so don't even think about them*.

---

#I suppose 'she' does not know her thinking is harmful, otherwise it sounds a bit strange to me because in case she knows about her ability, then she is intentionally doing harm, so the monster should beg her just to stop.