# Is my understanding correct on this sentence? Particularly, use of だけでも

Tags: grammar, interpretation

> 話だけでも聞いてから結論を述べれば良いだろう
> Even if its just a story, you should probably state your conclusion after hearing it.

The main thing I'm sceptical about is that だけでも, does it mean "even if it's..." in this context?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93792/45489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Even if it's...* is more simply でも. だけ is *just, only*. So overall *Even if it's just the story*.

Since 話 is the object of 聞く, it is a bit hard to use *even if it's just..* here. I'd translate it as *You should listen at least to the story and then conclude*.

Semantically, *at least* modifies *listen to*. It says, *You should listen to the story at least and conclude, rather than giving the final conclusion without even listening to it*. Also note that the *story* here means something like *what (someone) has to say*.

---

Some other examples:

- 味噌汁だけでも飲みなさい Eat miso soup at least! (eating nothing is bad for your health)
- 君だけでも助かってほしい I hope at least you survive ('I' may not be surviving).
- 1万円だけでももらえるならうれしい Even if it's just 10000 yen, receiving it makes me happy.